# PowerShell fails trying to get content from a shared folder from a remote computer

Tags: windows-7, powershell

We are using the following software:

- PowerShell v1
- Windows 7 Professional

When I run the following on a **remote** computer in PowerShell all works correctly:
*(the files from the shared folder are shown)*

```
Get-ChildItem "\\<NAME OF COMPUTER WHICH HOSTS THE NETWORK SHARE>\ourNetworkShare"
```

But when I run the following from my **local** computer:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <REMOTE COMPUTERNAME> 
-ScriptBlock { 
    Get-ChildItem '\\<NAME OF COMPUTER WHICH HOSTS THE NETWORK SHARE>\ourNetworkShare' 
}
-credential $myCredential
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find path '\\<NAME OF COMPUTER WHICH HOSTS THE NETWORK SHARE>\ourNetworkShare' 
because it does not exist. + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: 
(\\<NAME OF COMPUTER WHICH HOSTS THE NETWORK SHARE>....ourNetworkShare:String) 
[Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it work from the cmd prompt with the dir command?

Comment: No, as a surprise to me, it doesn't work. If i run cd \\server-name\ourNetworkShare on the remote computer in cmd following error comes: CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories

Comment: Is the \\Server\share in the scriptblock literal or from a local variable? Has the used credential access rights on the remote \\Server\share ?

Comment: Use `pushd \\server-name\ourNetworkShare` instead of `cd \\server-name\ourNetworkShare` in `cmd`. Try `(. net.exe view server-name) | Where-Object { $_ -match "^ourNetworkShare" }` as the scriptblock body.

Comment: Who said anything about cd? DIR \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME

Comment: @GregAskew see [_projekt-fisch_'s comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/863053/powershell-failes-when-on-a-remote-computer-trying-to-get-content-from-a-shared#comment1109620_863053): _If i run `cd \\server-name\ourNetworkShare`_…

Comment: @GregAskew DIR \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME on the remote-computer works fine.

Comment: @JosefZ (. net.exe view server-name) | Where-Object { $_ -match "^ourNetworkShare" } leads to a "Access is denied"

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like a [classic Kerberos delegate/double hop issue](https://4sysops.com/archives/using-credssp-for-second-hop-powershell-remoting/).  It can't enumerate the path because it can't delegate your credentials, so that's what I'd check first.  Try using the same method to connect to just the root of the computer - I'd expect you to get a credential error, but I don't recall the exact quirks of Powershell v1 and double hop credential delegation.

If you're able to resolve this problem by enabling CredSSP for second hop, you might consider making a GPO for that, and [you can find instructions on how to do so here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/enable-credssp-powershell).

On a related note, PowerShell 1 is ancient and shouldn't be used any more.  [Download an updated WMF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) and start using a more modern version of PowerShell.

Comment: This answer sounds plausible. Because I have no access to things like GPO or similar in this intranet, I have to stop my initiative now. Originally I thought my problem is solvable with better PS commands. Probably it isn't and I know that now. Thanks a lot!